# How to use Image carousel in polymer

Tags: javascript, carousel, polymer

I want to add an image carousel to my website which i am building using polymer(https://www.polymer-project.org/). But i am unable to find any core element/paper element with that functionality.
However i found a library that does that (https://github.com/addyosmani/polymer-ui-carousel) but not able to implement it. Please help me to implement image carousel in my polymer website.

The code that i am using is :-

```
<html class="polymer-ui-full-bleed">
    <head>

          <title>Just a new app</title>

          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">

          <script src="../bower_components/platform/platform.js"></script>

          <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/font-roboto/roboto.html">
          <link rel="import"
          href="../bower_components/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html">
          <link rel="import"
              href="../bower_components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html">
          <link rel="import"
              href="../bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
          <link rel="import" href="post-card.html">
          <link rel="import" href="post-list.html">
          <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer-ui-carousel/polymer-ui-carousel.html">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/polymer-ui-base-css/base.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/polymer-ui-carousel/smoke.css">

          <style>
          html,body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            background-color: #E5E5E5;
            font-family: 'RobotoDraft', sans-serif;
          }
          .container {
            width: 80%;
            margin: 50px auto;
          }
          @media (min-width: 481px) {
            #tabs {
              width: 200px;
            }
            .container {
              width: 400px;
            }
          }
          core-header-panel {
          height: 100%;
          overflow: auto;
          -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; 
        }
        core-toolbar {
          background: #03a9f4;
          color: white;
        }
        #tabs {
          width: 100%;
          margin: 0;
          -webkit-user-select: none;
          -moz-user-select: none;
          -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
          text-transform: uppercase;
        }
          </style>


        </head>

        <body class="polymer-ui-body-text polymer-ui-full-bleed polymer-ui-light-bg" unresolved>

            <core-header-panel>

          <core-toolbar>

            <paper-tabs id="tabs" selected="all" self-end>
            <paper-tab name="all">All</paper-tab>
            <paper-tab name="favorites">Favorites</paper-tab>
          </paper-tabs>
          </core-toolbar>
          <div class="container" layout vertical center>

          <post-list show="all"></post-list>

          <h1>&lt;polymer-ui-carousel&gt;</h1>
          <h2>With bullet controls</h2>

          <polymer-ui-carousel>
            <div>One</div>
            <div>Two</div>
            <div>Three</div>
            <div>Four</div>
            <div>Five</div>
          </polymer-ui-carousel>

        </div>




          <!-- main page content will go here --> 

        </core-header-panel>


        <script>
          var tabs = document.querySelector('paper-tabs');
          var list = document.querySelector('post-list');

            tabs.addEventListener('core-select', function() {
              list.show = tabs.selected;
            });

          tabs.addEventListener('core-select', function() {
            console.log("Selected: " + tabs.selected);
          });
        </script>
        </body>

    </html>
```

After installing Polymer-ui-carousel(https://github.com/addyosmani/polymer-ui-carousel) i am getting this error.

```
Exception caught during observer callback: TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null
    at polymer-ui-carousel.items (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/polymer-selector/polymer-selector.html:220:28)
    at polymer-ui-carousel.Polymer.valueToSelection (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/polymer-selector/polymer-selector.html:278:30)
    at polymer-ui-carousel.Polymer.updateSelected (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/polymer-selector/polymer-selector.html:255:16)
    at polymer-ui-carousel.Polymer.selectedChanged (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/polymer-selector/polymer-selector.html:245:14)
    at polymer-ui-carousel.g.invokeMethod (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/polymer/polymer.js:13:25932)
    at polymer-ui-carousel.g.notifyPropertyChanges (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/polymer/polymer.js:13:24037)
    at Object.x.report_ (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/polymer/polymer.js:12:18266)
    at Object.S.check_ (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/polymer/polymer.js:12:22604)
    at c (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/polymer/polymer.js:12:12173) polymer.concat.js:4861x.report_ polymer.concat.js:4861S.check_ polymer.concat.js:5264c polymer.concat.js:4757
```

Comment: Its always best to post the code you have so far so we can help you.

Comment: @ChargerIIC Thanks for replying. I am stuck at the first command. i.e $ bower install --save polymer-ui-carousel. when i am running this command nothing is happening it just keeps on displaying the blank cursor.

Comment: Hello, did you resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Import Web Components' polyfill:

```
<script src="platform.js"></script>
```

Import Custom Element:

```
<link rel="import" href="polymer-ui-carousel.html">
```

Start using it! Simple include your code instaed of

With bullet controls:

```
<polymer-ui-carousel>
  <div>here your code</div>
  <div>here your code</div>
  <div>here your code</div>
  <div>and so on</div>
</polymer-ui-carousel>
```

With text label controls:

```
<polymer-ui-carousel labels="true">
  <div title="Alpha">here your code</div>
  <div title="Beta">here your code</div>
  <div title="Gamma">here your code</div>
  <div title="Delta">and so on</div>
</polymer-ui-carousel>
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex Filatov for the reply but i am not able to install the package. I am stuck at the first command. i.e $ bower install --save polymer-ui-carousel. when i am running this command nothing is happening it just keeps on displaying the blank cursor.

Comment: Do you install Bower 'npm install -g bower' ?

Comment: In manual for this plugin toy should install ```Bower``` and ```Node.js```, ```Gulp``` for testing locally

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already installed node.js and i am using Yeoman(yeoman.io/learning/index.html) which is a combination of YO , BOWER and GRUNT(alternate of gulp).

Answer (score 0):

Your install will contain a bower folder with a child folder of `/bower_components`. You will want to type the `bower install --save polymer-ui-carousel` command while in that directory. You can get around this by adding bower to your Environment Path (depending on your operating system).

Once you type the command in you should see a new child folder in `/bower_components` that will contain the polymer-ui-carousel.html file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now i am able to install the package but now i am getting error that i have edited in my question.

Comment: Cool. Now we are back to a code problem. Looks like the carousel doesn't know which div to show first. Take a look at Alex Filatov answer and compare the code. If you don't see a difference, post what you have and we'll help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have added the code that i am using. I have compared the code but not able to identify what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Since you are using Bower, the path you want in your import href should start with '../bower_components/polymer-ui-carousel/polymer-ui-carousel.html' since it needs to point to where the actual polymer-ui-carousel.html is.

Comment: thanks for the reply i have changed the path as mentioned and updated the code but still same error. Also i am not getting any path not found error.

Comment: For me `bower install --save polymer-ui-carousel` says `fatal: remove error. Repository not found`! Is this not available any more? I am using Polymer 1.0